# Joomla using wrong version of PHP?

Tags: php, joomla, php-5.3

I am running an old Ubuntu 11.04 Natty server and I have PHP 5.3.5 installed, and thats what shows up when I view the `phpinfo();`.

However, Joomla seems to think I am running a version less than that. I keep getting this error: **"Your host needs to use PHP 5.3.10 or higher to run this version of Joomla!"**

What is going on here? Is Apache using the wrong version of PHP or is something wrong with my Joomla installation?

Comment: I was confused regarding PHP versions and failed to do my research before posting.

Answer (score 4):

5.3.5 < 5.3.10 there is not much more to say.

Basically what the error message tells you.

Comment: Oh? That logically doesn't make sense to me. I just assumed 5.3.10 meant 5.3.1.

Comment: It is not some decimal number. It is a versioning scheme. Think major.minor.patch

Answer (score 0):

Joomla apparently requires PHP version 5.3.10 to be installed on your server to run. To bypass this error you need to upgrade your PHP version

Run the following commands on your box to upgrade your php version:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php5
```